# Помогите пожалуйста реализовать часть кода, что-то не выходит, не могу понять

Tags: python

Не реализовывается последняя функция X0()

```
pole =[[" "] * 3 for i in range(3)]


def hello(): #приветсвие
    print("---")
    print("Приветствую вас в игре Крестики - Нолики")
    print("x - номер строки")
    print("y - номер столбца")
    print("---")
hello()
def field(): #ввод из консоли
    print(f"  0 1 2")
    for i in range(3):
        print(f"{i} {pole[i][0]} {pole[i][1]} {pole[i][2]}")
field()
def pass_():
    while True:
        cords = (input("Ваш ход: ").split())
        x, y = cords
        if len(cords) != 2:
            print("Неверное значение")
        else:
            if x.isdigit() and y.isdigit():
                x, y = int(x), int(y)
                if 0 <= x <= 2 and 0 <= y <= 2:
                    if pole[x][y] == " ":
                        return pole[x][y]
                    else:
                        print("Клетка занята")
                else:
                    print("Неверные значения")
            else:
                print("Введите числа")
    return cords
pass_()


def X0():
    count = 2
    for i in count:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            print("Введите Х!")
            count += 1
        else:
            print("Введите 0!")
            count += 1
X0(cords)
```

Comment: Не реализовывается последняя функция X0()

Comment: А что эта функция должна делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот возможное решение, если я правильно понял Ваш запрос. Немного подредактировал Ваши описания, так было удобнее при тестировании, при необходимости можете вернуть свои :)

Протестируйте. Все функции должны работать должным образом :)

```python
def hello(): 
    # Приветствие
    print("---")
    print("Приветствую вас в игре Крестики - Нолики")
    print("x - номер строки")
    print("y - номер столбца")
    print("---")


def field():
    # Вывод поля на консоль
    print(f"  0 1 2")
    for i in range(3):
        print(f"{i} {pole[i][0]} {pole[i][1]} {pole[i][2]}")


def pass_():
    # Получаем координаты хода от пользователя и возвращаем их,
    # если введены неверные данные или клетка уже занята, - запрашиваем новые
    while True:
        cords = input("Ваш ход: ").split()
        if len(cords) != 2:
            raise ValueError("Вы должны ввести две координаты через пробел")
        x, y = cords
        if not (x.isdigit() and y.isdigit()):
            print("Введите числа")
            continue
        x, y = int(x), int(y)
        if not (0 <= x <= 2 and 0 <= y <= 2):
            print("Неверные значения")
            continue
        if pole[x][y] != " ":
            print("Клетка занята")
            continue
        return x, y


def X0():
    # Ход игрока и выводит текущего состояние поля
    count = 2
    while True:
        if count % 2 == 0:
            symbol = "0"
        else:
            symbol = "X"
        print(f"Ходит игрок {symbol}")
        x, y = pass_()
        pole[x][y] = symbol
        field()
        count += 1


pole =[[" "] * 3 for i in range(3)]
hello()
field()

while True:
    try:
        x, y = pass_()
        pole[x][y] = "X"
        field()
        X0()
        # здесь можно добавить код проверки на победу
        # и прервать цикл, если игрок уже победил
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        # аналогично
        pass
```